# The view path doesnot exists in yii2 in server

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app

[The view path doesnot exist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MfEIZ.jpg).It is working fine on local but when deploy on server the view path doesnot exits.

Comment: Not much to go on here.. Maybe you should elaborate. Have you verified that the view files was correctly uploaded? Are the .htaccess files uploaded? Does the server accept mod rewrite?

Comment: Are you using yii2-advanced template or Yii2-basic tenplate?

Comment: Show the backend config/main.php entry content for user module